SQL query not fetching correct number of records
I have this SQL query. When I specify the date and time explicitly, it shows the correct number of rows:
select *
from annual_report_order
where report_order_date >= '29-OCT-2024 00:00:00.000'
  and report_order_date <= '02-NOV-2024 23:59:59.000'

However, when I use sysdate, output shows fewer rows:
select *
from annual_report_order
where report_order_date >= sysdate - 5
  and report_order_date <= sysdate - 1

Column report_order_date is defined as TIMESTAMP(6).
My aim is to automate this and use a scheduler, and run this SQL query every Sunday with report_order_date condition from Monday 00:00 till Saturday 23:59:59.
Could you please advise why sysdate shows fewer rows?

You can replace sysdate keywords with TRUNC(sysdate), it will yield the same result as long as the current date is November3rd, 2024

Think logically, what do you think the value of sysdate is? It contains the current date and time.

Use TO_DATE function
Sysdate is keeping timestamp, means it stores current minute, hour and seconds with date. It is creating the problem in keeping range of timespan in your resultset. The following SQL statement is showing the problem and solution.
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-2,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24 MI SS') stamp, TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY')-2,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24 MI SS') AS OnlyDate FROM DUAL;




Stamp
OnlyDate




02-NOV-2024 01 10 23
02-NOV-0024 00 00 00



In the first column Stamp date with hour, minute and second. but in second column it is with OnlyDate. builtin TO_DATE function with date format makes the difference.
There is a problem with TO_DATE function on  DATE data type, it returns only last two digits of year of date. But, with string type data of date value it works properly. The followings tricks used to solve the issue.
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(to_char(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY'),'DD-MM-YYYY'),'DD-MON-YYYY') AS OnlyDate

In your case the solution is
select *
from annual_report_order
where report_order_date >= TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(to_char(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY'),'DD-MON-YYYY')-5,'DD-MON-YYYY')
  and report_order_date <=  TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(to_char(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY'),'DD-MON-YYYY')-1,'DD-MON-YYYY')


The solution is implemented on oracle xe 21c.
Thanks

This fails in an international environment fiddle. And generally, don't compare dates to strings as it forces Oracle to do an implicit conversion of the string back to a date (so you convert a date to a string and back to a date and then back to a string and then Oracle will implicitly convert it back to a date to perform the comparison which is pointless and can cause additional errors).

A DATE is stored in a binary format consisting of 7 bytes representing: century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second and ALWAYS contains those components. A TIMESTAMP also may contain fractional seconds.
SYSDATE is a DATE and has all those components including hours, minutes and seconds and those components are at the current instant.
Your query:
SELECT *
FROM   annual_report_order
WHERE  report_order_date >= sysdate - 5
AND    report_order_date <= sysdate - 1

Finds values from 5 days before the current instant up until 1 day before the current instant.
What you want is:
SELECT *
FROM   annual_report_order
WHERE  report_order_date >= TRUNC(sysdate) - 5
AND    report_order_date <  TRUNC(sysdate) - 1

Which will find values from 5 days before midnight of the current day up until, but not including 1 day before midnight of the current day.

Sysdate-5  means it will apply -5 to date but timestamp remains whatever the current timestamp. So that might be the reason you are getting lesser records.
